# jQuery ajaxComplete: Is there a way to tell which Javascript function executed the ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the .ajaxComplete event wired up to a few elements like this:

`$("#ElementId").ajaxComplete(function (a, b, c) { });`

The issue is that I have multiple `$.ajax` calls in my script that are called by various functions.  I don't want the .ajaxComplete event to fire for every control for every ajax call.  Conceptually, I am looking for something like this:

`if (a.function == SearchCustomers) { do this }`

Is there any way to achieve what I want here?

**Edit:**  I realize that I can check for the URL of the service I am calling, but I don't want to hardcode a URL string in my scripts more than once.

Comment: Yeah, don't use `.ajaxComplete` global and instead attach a complete function to each call.

Comment: ...Or rather `success` in $.ajax rather than `complete`. Consistent naming would be too easy!

Comment: Your case is straight forward and the `success` property is obviously what you should use, but in case you have a situation where you need `ajaxComplete` to behave exactly the way you stated in the question, do look at what I've posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "servicecall.html",
    success: function(html){
        //if success
    };
});
```

Comment: My brain is fried. I am using success already and somwehow didn't think to put a call to my other function at the end of the one I am using in success. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

**Update**

Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Z5e/4/

---

You can specify a function identifier in a custom property in your `.ajax()` call and use the value of that in your `ajaxComplete()` callback.

For example, add a `'func'` property while making your `.ajax()` call:

```
function foo() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/someurl',
        ...
        func: 'foo',
        ...
    });
}
```

And then, use the value of that from your `ajaxComplete()`

```
$('#someElement').ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.func == 'foo') {
        // ... 
    }
    else if (settings.func == 'bar') {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, You saved my day! you can just log 'settings' to see if there's more exact data you can build your 'if' on.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like to have my modules organized in JS objects and than abstract my Ajax calls into functions for various reasons:

```
​var YourModule = {
    Ajax: {        
        AjaxCallOne: function()
        {
            return $.ajax({
                // your options for the call    
            }).promise();
        },
        AjaxCallTwo: function()
        {
            return $.ajax({
                // your options for the call    
            }).promise();
        }
    },
    Events: {
        OnButtonOneClick: function()
        {
            YourModule.Ajax.AjaxCallOne().then(YourModule.Events.OnAjaxCallOneReceived);
        },
        OnButtonOneClick: function()
        {
            YourModule.Ajax.AjaxCallTwo().then(YourModule.Events.OnAjaxCallTwoReceived);
        },
        OnAjaxCallOneReceived:function(data)
        {
            // your code            
        },
        OnAjaxCallTwoReceived: function(data)
        {
            // your code    
        }
    }            
};​​​
```

.then() is working since $.ajax implements the Deferred "interface". See this reference:
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Also, think about giving the code user the ability to alter the options passed into the $.ajax calls. For this, I use $.extend. See this reference:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 1):

Ajax call one:

```
$.ajax({
    // set all your properties as needed
    url: myUrl,
    success: function(data) {
        // handle the result from THIS .ajax call
    }
});
```

Ajax call two:

```
$.ajax({
    // set all your properties as needed
    url: myotherURL,
    success: function(data) {
        // handle the result from THIS .ajax call
    }
});
```

If you have a lot of .ajax calls that need to do the same thing, then you can use $.ajaxSetup to set a default success function