# Send JSON and HTTPRequest to server AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-chrome

I'm trying to send `json` data and `Http headers` to a server

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
{
    username: '',
    password: '',
    actions: {
        login: function(){
            username = this.get('username');
            password = this.get('password');
            // alert("User: "+ username + " Pass: " + password);
    
            var loginData = {"code":username, "passkey":password};
            loginData = JSON.stringify(loginData);
            // alert(loginData);
            var timeStamp = getTimeStamp();
            // alert(timeStamp);
    
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://192.168.254.222:8080/project/auth/login',
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function (request)
                {
                   request.setRequestHeader("token", authToken);
                },
                data: loginData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {
                    var returned_data = data;
                    console.log(returned_data);
                    console.log(returned_data.error); 
                    alert('yey!');
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error){
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

1. but the variable `err` returns **undefined**.
2. Also I'm not sure how to send multiple `HttpRequest headers` to the server, and at the same time get the `HttpReponse headers`.
3. And chrome gives me this:

> Denying load of
> chrome-extension://nhjloagockgobfpopemejpgjjechcpfd/js/jquery.min.map.
> Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key
> in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
> localhost/webui/:
>
> GET chrome-extension://invalid/

Aside from these I don't get any error message in Firefox

Comment: To avoid chrome console error, just `remove the first comment line from jQuery.min.js` file for min.map file.

Comment: if this is `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` what you're talking about, I included the dependency from the cloud

Answer (score 0):

[From AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

`dataType` - The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. Hope you are returning json response

check `authToken` is string?

```
 beforeSend: function (request)
 {
   request.setRequestHeader("token", authToken); 
 }
```

Also add [.ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings )](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) and see what you are getting here

Also for setting HttpHeader you can write a server code depends on the technology you  use

I write the below for ASP.Net

```
 response.Content.Headers.Add("some_header", "Value");
```

To read this in jQuery ajax success callback

```
     $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.254.222:8080/project/auth/login',
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function (request)
            {
               request.setRequestHeader("token", authToken);
            },
            data: loginData,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
                var returned_data = data;
                alert(request.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, errMsg){

            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, `token: 7ffed684cbe1fc085b7b47dc4e508e99a5effee9` this is the value, it's just a normal string. The server will return a `json` string and `HttpResponse headers` which I need to get

Comment: @shin-shan, are you going to send HttpHeader to server `or` Retreive it from server?

Comment: after I send the `json` and the `HttpRequest headers`, the server will return me a `json` string and I need to get the `HttpResponse headers`

Comment: wouldn't `.ajaxComplete` be in contrast to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976130/jquery-ajaxcomplete-is-there-a-way-to-tell-which-javascript-function-executed-t) ? I just need to debug `error: function ()` to see what am I missing

Comment: @shin-shan, No. You can use this callback whenever you need to do something when ajax fails or success. But in your case, if you return data and header successfully, you can use `success` only

Comment: that's why it has `error` so that it could tell me what happen with the request, isn't it?

Comment: @shin-shan, sometime if you get any strange behaviour you can use complete

Comment: I got lost in there, I'm not sure how to put it in the code, I suppose I need to redo the whole structure?

Comment: @shin-shan updated answer with the `success` which is what you require in your case

Comment: it says `TypeError: err is undefined`

Comment: @shin-shan, there was a issue in your error callback. check my updated answer

Comment: the `alert("error: " + errMsg)` is empty.. I tried playing with it earlier and I got these results, `[object object]`, an empty error msg, error as undefined, and undefined `error` variable.

Comment: @shin-shan, please check the response in console of your browser(Firefox/Chrome) and see what object it actually returns. Based on that you change your code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38429/discussion-between-shin-shan-and-murali)

Comment: using `console.log(errMsg)` there's nothing on the console

Comment: @shin-shan, sorry I have no idea what is the issue you are getting.. You got all the right code. still if you see nothing but error mean what we do :(

Comment: that's ok, I appreciate it. How about sending multiple `HttpRequest headers` ??

Comment: @shin-shan, repeat this `request.setRequestHeader("header-name", value)` for different header and value

Comment: I was able to print out the `errMsg` by changing the `dataType` to `jsonp` though the `errMsg` says `error` nothing specific